# Как правильно забиндить свойство Text RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Постигаю MVVM вместе с MVVM Light и у меня возникла проблема с RichTextBox. Его свойство Text я забиндил и из ViewModel его менять получается, но вот когда нужно во ViewModel получить доступ к строкам, которые пользователь напечатал во RichTextBox, то я постоянно получаю null. Как это исправить?
Не знаю имеет ли значение, но на всякий случай уточню что я ещё использую MahApps.Metro.

```
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBoxOther"
                             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <FlowDocument PageWidth="1000">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding RichTextBoxOther_Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
```

```cs
    private string _richTextBoxOther_Text;
    public string RichTextBoxOther_Text
    {
        get { return _richTextBoxOther_Text; }
        set
        {
            _richTextBoxOther_Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => RichTextBoxOther_Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, то никак. Новые `Paragraph`'ы и `Inline`'ы могут добавляться в контрол при вводе пользователя.

`RichTextBox` не выставляет наружу свойства, к которым можно биндиться. (Вы можете забиндить только текст, который вы сами формируете, и не даёте пользователю на редактирование.) Но он содержит свойство `Document`, ссылающееся на `FlowDocument`, который по сути и является VM для `RichTextBox`'а.

Поэтому если вы хотите применить MVVM-подход, вынесите `FlowDocument` в VM и оперируйте им там.